# Drop down navigation menu not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu

http://wnmu.publicbroadcasting.net/test.html

I am trying to get the menu here working.  Works perfectly in Firefox and Chrome, but it won't work in Internet Explorer.  I tried both IE8 and IE9 including Compatibility View and none of the drop downs show up at all.

Here's the HTML from the header:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<a href="http://wnmufm.org" target="_self"><img src="http://www.wnmufm.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/pr90-banner.jpg" border="0"></a><br>
<div id="nav">
<ul id="menu" class="menu">
<li><a href="http://wnmu.publicbroadcasting.net/index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.publicbroadcasting.net/wnmu/news.newsmain">News</a>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="http://events.publicbroadcasting.net/wnmu/events.eventsmain">Events Calendar</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://wnmufm.org/category/news/">Regional News</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.publicbroadcasting.net/wnmu/news.newsmain?action=section&SECTION_ID=2">National News</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.publicbroadcasting.net/wnmu/news.newsmain?action=section&SECTION_ID=3">World News</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.publicbroadcasting.net/wnmu/arts.artsmain">Arts News</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.publicbroadcasting.net/wnmu/news.newsmain?action=section&SECTION_ID=5">Business News</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://wnmufm.org/schoolclosings/">School Closings</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="http://wnmufm.org/localprograms">Programming</a>
    <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="http://wnmufm.org/localprograms">Local Programs</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.publicbroadcasting.net/wnmu/guide.guidemain">Program Guide</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.publicbroadcasting.net/wnmu/guide.guidemain?action=searchPlaylist&playlistID=0">Search Playlist</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://wnmu.publicbroadcasting.net/media/Preview%20PDF/WNMU-FM_Preview_May11.pdf">Download May Preview</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="http://wnmufm.org/livestream">Listen to PR90</a>
    <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="http://wnmufm.org/livestream">PR90 Live Stream</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://wnmufm.org/sportsstream">NMU Sports Stream</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.publicbroadcasting.net/wnmu/.jukebox?action=programs">PR90 Podcasts</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://wnmufm.org/nprpodcasts">NPR Podcasts</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="http://wnmufm.org/support">Support Us</a>
    <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="https://secure.publicbroadcasting.net/wnmu/default/form.pledgemain">Make A Pledge</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://secure.publicbroadcasting.net/wnmu/default/viewpremiums.pledgemain?newSearch=true&premiumType=all&orderBy=amount">Thank You Gifts</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://wnmufm.org/matchinggifts">Matching Gifts</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://wnmufm.org/underwriter">Become An Underwriter</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://wnmufm.org/support">Ways to Give</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="http://wnmufm.org/insidepr90">Inside PR90</a>
    <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="http://wnmufm.org/evelyn">Manager's Message</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://wnmufm.org/history">Station History</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://wnmufm.org/staff">PR90 Staff</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://wnmufm.org/employment">Job Openings</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://wnmufm.org/contact">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</body></html>
```

And here's the menu CSS:

```css
#nav
{
    width:974px;
    min-height:33px;
    background:#d5c6a6 url(http://wnmufm.org/wp-content/themes/cover-wp/images/menu.png);
    text-align:bottom;
}

ul#menu, .menu ul
{
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    font-family:Georgia, "URW Bookman L", serif;
    font-size:14px;
    padding-right:285px;
    margin:0;

}

ul#menu li, .menu ul li
{
    float:left;
    padding:0 5px;
    margin:7px 0;
    border-right:#333333 1px dotted;
    margin-left:0;
}

ul#menu li a:link, ul#menu li a:visited, .menu ul li a:link, .menu ul li a:visited
{
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    padding:0 15px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#333333;
}


ul#menu li a:hover, ul#menu li a:active, .menu ul li a:hover, .menu ul li a:active, ul#menu li.current_page_item a, .menu ul li.current_page_item a:link, .menu ul li.current_page_item a:visited, .menu ul li.current_page_item a:hover, .menu ul .current_page_item a:active
{
    background-color:#ffffff;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#cc3300;
}

ul#menu li li
{
    border-right:none;
    margin:0;
    margin-top:0px;
    min-width:120px;
    padding:0;
    float:none;
}

ul#menu li li li
{
    padding-left:1px;
}

ul#menu li li a, ul#menu li li a:link, ul#menu li li a:visited
{
    background:#d5c6a6 url(http://wnmufm.org/wp-content/themes/cover-wp/images/submenu.png) bottom;
    min-width:120px;
    color:#333333;
    font-size:14px;
    font-family:Georgia, "URW Bookman L", serif;
    margin:0;
    line-height:25px;
    text-align:left;
}

ul#menu li li a:hover, ul#menu li li a:active
{
    background:#FFFFFF;
    color:#cc3300;
}

ul#menu li ul
{
    z-index:9999;
    position:absolute;
    left:-999em;
    height:auto;
    min-width:150px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
}

ul#menu li ul a
{ 
    min-width:120px;
}

ul#menu li ul ul
{
    margin:-26px 0 0 150px;
}

ul#menu li:hover ul ul, ul#menu li:hover ul ul ul
{
    left:-999em;
}

ul#menu li:hover ul, ul#menu li.sfhover ul, ul#menu li li:hover ul, ul#menu li li.sfhover ul, ul#menu li li li:hover ul, ul#menu li li li.sfhover ul
{
    left: auto;
}

ul#menu li:hover, ul#menu li.sfhover
{ 
    position: static;
}
```

I appreciate any help.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Your HTML contains a stray `<?xml version="1.0"?>`, which should be at the *very **top*** of the page. On the URL that you gave, you have elements such as `<pi_page_head>` and `<pi_page_foot>` that do not exist, and you don't have a doctype, so your document renders as quirks mode.

Comment: Elements such are pi_page_head I think is the code used by the host (Public Interactive) that grabs the header, footer, and other elements to build the page.  Kind of like WordPress works.

I'm still new to using Public Interactive's website, which they use to build their webpage, and I'm not sure of all the limitations yet (i.e. if there is a way to put the xml version at the very top of the page, etc...).

Comment: If those are supposed to be for some sort of content management or templating system, then you are using it wrong. Those tags will be ignored by browsers and you still have to fix the issues mc10 mentioned. Chances are you can total remove all of those pi_ related tags and everything will still work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where your css stylesheet is connected example link ="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

and If you had your css style on your HTML page it should be in between open and close style tags.
I tried to write the code out for you about the first example, for some reason it blank the hyperlink out. before the word link a < is there and after link then a space and  href and everything else ="style.css" you would know your css was attached to your html page. Yes I just went to a Template site your css page got to be attached <  link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"type=" type="text/css">